# Sqlite_3 distance function

Tags: ios, sqlite, location

Hi am developing an application which stores current location coordinates in to database,and when a person reaches the same(with in 100 meters) location for second time I need to show an alert.for this I am using the distance for sqlite provided in stack-overflow after opening the sqlite database .and then I am using

```
SELECT * from table ORDER BY distance
```

I used this code....

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK) {

    sqlite3_create_function(dataBase, "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &distanceFunc, NULL, NULL);
   NSString *sqlQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ ORDER BY distance(uacl_latitude,uacl_lognitude,%f,%f)",NSLocalizedString(@"TABLE_USER_LOCATION", nil),[self.currentLatitude doubleValue],[self.currentLongitude doubleValue]];

    NSLog(@"%@",sqlQuery);
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt = NULL;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase,[sqlQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],-1,&selectstmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            self.latitude =sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 4);
            self.longitude = sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 5);                NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.latitude],@"LATI",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.longitude],@"LONGI",nil];
            [array addObject:dict];
        }
    }
} else {
    //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.

    sqlite3_close(dataBase);
}
```

With this the distance function is not calling, and the prepareV2 statement is also not executing,if i replace the "`ORDERBY distance Query`" with `SELECT * from Table PrepareV2` is executing.
Any help please....

Comment: Call `sqlite3_errmsg` to get a useful error message.